# Could not find railsties

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I type

```
rails _4.2.0.rc2_ new hello_app
```

I get this error

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (=  4.2.0.rc2) - did find: [railties-4.1.8] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/a11/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I tried installing railsties 4.2.0.rc2 using

```
gem install railties --pre
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want try to use new rails version, you need execute

```
gem install rails --pre
```

instead of

```
gem install railties --pre
```

Railties its core of Rails framework but not in all. See [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed rails completely

```
gem uninstall railties -v 4.2.0.rc2

sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.0.rc2
```

and that solved it.